# do-release-upgrade how to continue after choosing D for "Remove obsolete packages?"

Tags: command-line, upgrade, usability

I was on 20.04, commands I ran on terminal to upgrade :

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo gedit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
do-release-upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-mark unhold   mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt full-upgrade  
do-release-upgrade
```

Was asked many questions ... wish we had a way to do a dry run, see all the questions, anwer them in a text file and then start this process, pinting to text file for answers (one line question, next line our answer, if any new questions, that were not found in the dry run - an option to auto default or prompt us)

Anyway was asked:

> Reading state information... Done
>
> Remove obsolete packages?
>
> 140 packages are going to be removed.
>
> Removing the packages can take several hours.
>
> Continue [yN]  Details [d]d

Choose D. showed me the packages and then showed (END), see image

But after seeing the list, was not clear how to resume. Pressed Y (nothing happened), then pressed Esc, then pressed Ctrl-Z, it exited the install process.

Now `lsb_release -a`
says I'm on Ubuntu 21.10 but how do i remove those files? And why did the process exit?

From usability perspective would have helped if it told me how to resume when it showed the choices ...

Comment: Personally i would not use the minus y so I could see what is going on.

Comment: Yes good observation  @david

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit that display and continue the `do-release-upgrade` process.

Remove those orphaned packages using `sudo apt autoremove`.

You were on the final step of the `do-release-upgrade` process, so no further action to repair or continue is needed.

Here is the wrong place to make feature requests or complaints; we merely answer questions: [File a proper bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) about it in order to get the usability improved. Filing a bug takes about as much effort as asking a question here.

Comment: I agree, not the place bit sometimes get valuable pointers here. Thanks